# malloc and free vs new and delete

Tags: c++

Hello I read that `new` and `delete` is better than `malloc()` and `free()` because `free()` doesn't call a destructor while `delete` does...
eg:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class String
{
public:
    String();
    String(const String&){cout<<"String cpy ctor\n";}
    ~String();
private:
    int* itsParray;
};

String::String()
{
    cout<<"String ctor\n";
    itsParray=new int[100];
    for(int i(0);i<100;i++)
        itsParray[i]=i+1;
}

String::~String()
{
        cout<<"String dtor\n";
        delete[] itsParray;
        itsParray=NULL;
}

int main()
{
        String* pStr=NULL;
        pStr = static_cast<String* > (malloc(4 * sizeof(String)));
        free(pStr);

        pStr=new String[4];
        delete[] pStr;

        cout<<endl<<endl<<endl;
        return 0;
}
```

When I execute the program, I see that destructors of the four `String` objects were called when calling `delete` on `pStr`. but the four deleted by `free()` doesn't call destructors. Does this mean `free()` leads to memory leakage as long as there are pointers on the heap inside the class?

Comment: I guess you mean "new and **delete**".

Comment: `malloc` and `free` are both C functions, not C++ functions. You shouldn't use them in C++ code unless you're actually allocating stuff for a C library - in which case `new` and `delete` should work just fine anyway.

Comment: It means that destructors that should be called aren't. And this can lead to undefined behaviour. Also, don't get fixated on memory leaks. Classes can manage resources that aren't memory.

Comment: Also, `free()` doesn't cause memory leaks, bad programmers who use `free()` in C++ code do.

Comment: not only will `free` not call your object's destructor, but `malloc` won't call your objects constructor.

Comment: yes I meant new and delete vs malloc and free

Comment: "Does this mean `free()` leads to memory leakage as long as there are pointers on the heap inside the class?" – yes. Even worse, if you are copying an object with a non-trivial constructor into `malloc()`ated memory, then (because the copy takes over the space) the destructor of the allegedly previously-existent (but actually non-existent, uninitialized) object will be called – on the garbage-filled memory returned by `malloc()`, which leads to undefined behavior.

Comment: in my example free(pStr); is this a memory leak?

Comment: @Lacrymosa7: yes, because `~String()` is not called to free `itsParray`.

Comment: ok thanks guys I got it thanx to you all

Comment: @RemyLebeau are you sure? I'd say that: since he used `malloc`, the constructor was never called so the class isn't constructed.. so when he calls `free`, it frees the memory allocated by the `malloc` and so no leak ever occurred. However, IF he used `new` and `free`, then he'd be leaking. Is this not correct? @OP, always pair `new` with `delete`. Also, don't use `malloc` to allocate non-pod types. To be safe, always use `new` and `delete` in C++ or one of the memory-management containers such as `std::unique_ptr`.

Comment: @Brandon: Ok, true. No constructor called means no memory allocated, means no memory to leak when not calling the destructor. However, this is a very isolated example. In real world code, classes usually allocate memory throughout their lifetimes, not just in their constructors. And yes, you cannot mix `malloc()` with `delete`, or `new` with `free()` (or even mix `new` with `delete[]` and `new[]` with `delete`, for that matter).

Comment: yes I think that Brandon is true: as long as no ctor is invoked then no memory is allocated internally. to confirm this: just call the dtor in my example: pStr->~String(); the result is the crash of the program because calling a (delete) on non-inizialized pointer.

Comment: another thing: in my example using malloc()... no constructor is invoked so how to construct pStr elements??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`new` calls a constructor, `malloc()` does not.  `delete` calls a destructor, `free()` does not.  If the class in question allocates memory internally, then yes, you are likely to encounter a memory leak.

If you have to use `malloc()` and `free()` (and in C++, you really shouldn't be), you will have to use **placement new** to call the constructor, and call the destructor yourself, eg:

```
pStr = static_cast<String*>(malloc(4 * sizeof(String)));
if (pStr)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
        new (&pStr[i]) String;
    ...
    for (int i = 3; i >= 0; --i)
        pStr[i].~String();
    free(pStr);
}
```

And if you really need to mimic `new[]`, you should handle exceptions thrown by constructors, eg:

```
pStr = static_cast<String*>(malloc(4 * sizeof(String)));
if (!pStr)
    throw std::bad_alloc("");

int numConstructed = 0;
try
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
    {
        new (&pStr[i]) String;
        ++numConstructed;
    }
}
catch (const std::exception &)
{
    for (int i = numConstructed-1; i >= 0; ++i)
        pStr[i]).~String();
    throw;
}

...

for (int i = numConstructed-1; i >= 0; --i)
    pStr[i].~String();
free(pStr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  For C++ objects, you must use 'new' and 'delete.' 'new' will ensure that the object's constructor is called, and 'delete' will ensure that the object's destructor is called.

malloc() and free() are memory allocation routines (from the C world), but will not invoke constructors or destructors.  If those objects allocate memory themselves (either in the constructor, or during their lifetime), presumably the destructor will de-allocate that memory, but to make sure that happens, you must use 'delete' so that the destructor is called.

Also, don't mix new/delete with malloc/free.  That is, don't use 'new' followed by free() on the same object, or a malloc() followed by 'delete.'  It won't work.

FYI, 'new' may be implemented in terms of malloc() followed by calling an object's constructor.  'delete' may be implemented in terms of free() following a call to an object's destructor.  In fact, if you write class-specific 'new' and 'delete' methods, that is exactly how you would do it.